# Rails params method: Why can it be accessed like a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Viewing this code:

`params[:id]`

Params is considered to be a method. Correct me if I'm wrong there. But that's like reading from a hash. So, I'm currently confused.

If params is a method: **How does the shown code-example work?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct that `params` is a method, but here the `params` method returns an instance of `ActionController::Parameters` and we call hash accessor method `#[]` on it.

This is a common pattern in ruby to call methods on the returned object. Let's see it by a simple example:

```rb
def params
  {
    id: 101,
    key: 'value',
    foo: 'bar'
  }
end

params[:id] # => 101
params[:foo] # => 'bar'
```

As you can see in the example, method `params` returns a hash object and we call hash accessor method `#[]` on the returned object.

Reference to rails `params` method: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5e1a039a1dd63ab70300a1340226eab690444cea/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L1215-L1225

```rb
def params
  @_params ||= begin
    context = {
      controller: self.class.name,
      action: action_name,
      request: request,
      params: request.filtered_parameters
    }
    Parameters.new(request.parameters, context)
  end
end
```

Note for ruby beginners: In ruby, we can call methods without parenthesis. So, above call is equivalent to `params()[:id]`.

Comment: Great answer, maybe it will be helpful to add that it is equivalent to `params()[:id]`

Answer (score 3):

Those are known as square bracket accessors and you can add them to any object by implementing the `[]` and `[]=` methods.

```
class Store
  def initialize(**kwargs)
    kwargs.each { |k,v| instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) }
  end
  
  def [](key)
    instance_variable_get("@#{key}")
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
  end
end


store = Store.new(foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3)
store[:foo] # 1
store[:foo] = 100
store[:foo] # 100
```

Also when you call `params[:id]` - the `params` method will be called first so you're calling `[]` on an instance of ActionController::Parameters just like in this simplefied example:

```
def foo
  Store.new(bar: 1)
end

foo[:bar] # 1
```

Since parens are optional its equivilent to calling `params()[:id]`.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a Controller, `params` is indeed a method. Let's say we have an `OrganizationsController` that is exposing the `#index` action in a restful endpoint. I will add a breakpoint using the [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) gem so that we can better understand what `params` is:

```rb
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    binding.pry  # Runtime will stop here
    render json: Organization.all
  end
end
```

And let's visit the following URL:

http://localhost:3000/organizations.json?foo=bar

We can actually verify that `params` is a method by explicitly calling it with `()`:

```rb
> params()
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"foo"=>"bar", "controller"=>"organizations", "action"=>"index", "format"=>"json"} permitted: false>
```

or by actually asking Ruby where that method is defined:

```rb
> method(:params).source_location
=> ["/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2@myproject/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb", 1186]
```

The object returned by calling `params` is not a `Hash`, but an `ActionController::Parameters` instead:

```rb
> params.class
=> ActionController::Parameters
```

However, we can call the method `:[]` on it because it is actually defined in the `ActionController::Parameters` class (see [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5e1a039a1dd63ab70300a1340226eab690444cea/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L638))

This makes it look like it's actually a `Hash`, but it is not, actually. For example, we cannot call the `Hash` method [invert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Hash.html#method-i-invert) on `params`, as it is not defined:

```rb
> params.invert
NoMethodError: undefined method `invert' for #<ActionController::Parameters {"foo"=>"bar", "controller"=>"organizations", "action"=>"index", "format"=>"json"} permitted: false>
```